# Where is BaseModel in AppEngine for Django 1.2?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm trying to write an Exporter class so I can extract my local development datastore to a CSV file. I'm using OS X 10.8.5 and GAE SDK 1.8.8. And we use Django 1.2 as provided by GAE.

My code is:

```
import sys
import os
import datetime
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.tools import bulkloader

module_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('./data/models.py'))
sys.path.insert(0, module_dir)
import models

class SomeObjectLoader(bulkloader.Loader):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkloader.Loader.__init__(self, 'SomeObject',
                                   [('product_name', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                                    ('project_id', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                                    ('asset', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                                    ('document_id', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                                    ('content_type', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                                    ('document_name', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
                                    ])
loaders = [FinalAuditDataLoader]
```

The models load OK but there is an ongoing reference to the BaseModel and I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/appcfg.py", line 196, in 
    run_file(**file**, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/appcfg.py", line 192, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4810, in 
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4801, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2611, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4495, in **call**
    return method()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4286, in PerformDownload
    run_fn(args)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4198, in RunBulkloader
    sys.exit(bulkloader.Run(arg_dict))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 4408, in Run
    return _PerformBulkload(arg_dict)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 4219, in _PerformBulkload
    LoadConfig(config_file)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 3879, in LoadConfig
    ('', 'r', imp.PY_SOURCE))
  File "loader.py", line 9, in 
    import models
  File "/Users/tim/work/lqe-tool/lqe_data/models.py", line 13, in 
    from appengine_django.models import BaseModel
ImportError: No module named appengine_django.models

Comment: http://pycruft.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/django-1-2-on-app-engine/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the codebase has an appengine_django.zip and that is where the appengine_django.* lie..